# Why doesn't my UITableView have a delegate outlet in storyboard?

Tags: swift, uistoryboard

I was wondering why my tableview doesn't have a delegate outlet in storyboard, but only data source?[image]

Is there a reason for this?

**Edit:**

This is what happens when I control click the TableView
[image]

And here is the IBOutlet in my ViewController:[image]

Comment: Are you using a `UITableView` or a subclass of `UITableView`?

Comment: Plain old TableView, I've tried it with a collection view as well and the delegate doesn't show up in the outlet tab as well. I've also tried to reinstall xCode and it still didn't work

Comment: What do you see if you control-click on the TableView in the Storyboard?

Comment: Same thing I've updated my question to show the screen shot

Comment: Can you add the definition of `SettingsTableView` to your question?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Make sure your class implements UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

EXAMPLE: class NewSettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
}

Answer (score 0):

Drag and connect delegate and the dataSource like this: 
[image]

Also make sure, your viewController conforms to the protocols.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {}
```